# Update statement not working properly in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, sql-update, ms-access-2013

In microsoft access:

```
Update Orders
Set TotalPrice  = (SELECT Max(Total)
FROM OrderDetails)
```

Can anyone please explain me why this doesn't work?

Comment: What error do you get?  Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: Please show what error are you getting here

Comment: Why are you doing this? It is against the principles of normalization.

Comment: I want to take a value from an existing table that i have and put it in a field in another table.. And i cant understand how to do it. This is just an example for me to understand but in my project it looks a little different. Can you give me an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your query fails with "Operation must use an updateable query" because the Access Database Engine tends to make queries "not updateable" if they use certain features like SQL aggregation functions (e.g., `MAX()`), outer joins, etc..

In your particular case the equivalent query for Access would use the `DMax()` domain aggregate function:

```sql
UPDATE Orders SET TotalPrice = DMax("Total", "OrderDetails")
```